# Transpose repeated values into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Day1 | 10 |
| 1 | A | Day2 | 9 |
| 2 | A | Day3 | 11 |
| 3 | B | Day1 | 12 |
| 4 | B | Day2 | 7 |
| 5 | B | Day3 | 5 |
| 6 | C | Day1 | 9 |
| 7 | C | Day2 | 10 |
| 8 | C | Day3 | 6 |

I want to transpose the columns so that it looks like this

| Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day1 | 10 | 12 | 9 |
| Day2 | 9 | 7 | 10 |
| Day3 | 11 | 5 | 6 |

Is there a way I can do that with Python? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called pivoting.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3 + ['C'] * 3, 'Col2': np.tile(['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3'], 3), 'Col3': [10, 9, 11, 12, 7, 5, 9, 10, 6]})
df.pivot('Col2', 'Col1', 'Col3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like @Alex shows you also there is another way that provides you more customization which is `pivot_table` which enables you to get average or any other aggregation on your data the default is `mean`

```
df.pivot_table(index="Col2",columns="Col1",values='Col3',aggfunc=sum)
```

[image]

```
df.pivot_table(index="Col2",columns="Col1",values='Col3',aggfunc='count')
```

[image]